# How to rotate background? trying to apply shadow

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to apply a shadow with api 15 so elevation do not count.
when I trying to apply a 9-path file I stood facing a problem... This:

[image]

mmmm have sense... the 9-paths file that I download was this[image]

but when I rotated the image I still having the same trouble...[image]

what can I do to rotate background?

Answer (score 0):

i dont known why but this roblem resolve after reset my PC

[image]